# MySQLDump without locking the tables

Tags: mysql

It seems that if you have many tables, you can only perform a MySQLDump without locking them all, otherwise you can an error.

What are the side effects of performing a MySQLDump without locking all the tables; Is the DB snapshot I get this way, consistent? Do I have any other alternative for getting a backup of a MySQL DB with many tables?

Comment: If you do need to lock can you also automate it at a quiet time, i.e. when database is least used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way (if using InnoDB) is actually to run the backup on a replicated slave. That way locking will be of no consequence.
Else just use the --single-transaction flag as mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

What storage engine(s) do you use?

If you are using InnoDB, then you can run mysqldump with the --single-transaction flag and get a consistent snapshot without locking the tables.

If you are using MyISAM, then you need to lock the tables to get a consistent snapshot. Otherwise any insert/update/delete statements that run on your MyISAM tables while mysqldump is running may or may not be reflected in the output depending on the timing of those statements.

Answer (score 2):

The --single-transaction flag should work if your DB is of type InnoDB.

Answer (score 1):

For Innodb , you need mention --single-transaction in mysqldump utility to avoid locking and get a consistent snapshot.

For MyISAM , you need to lock the tables to get consistent snapshot else you will miss DML to be logged while running dump